# spark-shell initiation error /tmp/hive not writable

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

I have installed Scala, Spark, SBT and winutils on the windows box. Also configured JAVA_HOME, SPARK_HOME, SCALA_HOME, SBT_HOME appropriately. Still, when I try to run 'spark-shell', I run into a very common problem which I see many people have faced.
I have tried giving access to c:/tmp/hive directory through winutils as well as through windows explorer. Yet the same issue. I would appreciate if anyone can tell me what else I might be missing?
Versions:
Spark: 2.1.1
Scala: 2.11
Below are the links to screenshots:
https://filedropper.com/filemanager/public.php?service=files&t=b5cc12549b9ae19ff969c65cb952c135

https://filedropper.com/filemanager/public.php?service=files&t=cb5b9b8f14980963be6f0a6511f71455

https://filedropper.com/filemanager/public.php?service=files&t=a2d471abfe57ca020a700c226b906faf

Appreciate your help!
Thanks,
Manish

Comment: `spark-shell` doesn't need to read `/tmp/hive` until you enable HiveSupport...

Comment: `spark-shell` **does** use a Hive-enabled `SparkSession` and so the need to configure that layer properly.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you cricket_007 and Jacek. I appreciate your comments.
It turned out an issue with version compatibility with winutils. Had to try several versions until the right version changed the permissions on /tmp/hive